# Porting Java web app to Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, tomcat, raspberry-pi, rxtx

I've got a web app called PiRail exported to a war file, which I want to port to a Tomcat server on a Raspberry Pi. There are a few issues I'm trying to get through to deal with this.

1. I've had no luck deploying the war file on any system so far. While Tomcat does work on the Pi, it doesn't seem to recognise PiRail.war.
2. PiRail depends on an extrnal library called RXTX, which caused no end of problems during development. I had to place the library in the project folder, so eclipse would recognize it and somewhere deep in a lot of Java files so that it would actually compile. Will this cause problems for running the war file?

Comment: Start at first with a war application with no dependenices to external libraries, just to check first whether any java war file is deployable to Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I've succeeded in deploying a simple war file on the Pi. For some reason though, I'm having trouble running anything on my Windows laptop, where Tomcat doesn't seem to work outside of Eclipse. Without it, it's really hard to compare whether something should work in the first place.

Comment: It seems you have a different problem. Please change your question to add the other problem of deploying tomcat applications in windows outside eclipse. Be sure to describe your problem in details and to copy all the relevant error messages

Comment: Which error messages does Tomcat throw while deploying?